# Is there a workaround to make sure a Collection in a shared workspace is not archived in Postman Free Team account?

Tags: postman

Our team is now more than 25 and I believe we have reached the shared history limits so Postman is automatically archiving collections. It is OK to archive some old ones, but then they are also archiving our Smoke Test which we run from time to time and some other developer collections that are used as reference by new team members. Has anyone found a way to select which Collection will remain unarchived?

- I've searched the net for some official comment from Postman and came accross this: [Archived Items in Free Teams Account Cannot be Deleted](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/5457). It seems the Postman team has no plan of adding a delete button to clear out the history.
- I also tried another work around that I saw wherein you download the archived data and re-share the specific collection that you want to be shared. I was able to share two collectections, but when I was out to share the 3rd one, the 2 got archived and I was left with only the 3rd one shared. It seems that this also generates multiple environment instances making it not really ideal since you have to do a cleanup as you do trial and error.

I just need to have at least 3 permanently shared collections.

Answer (score 2):

Shared history and collections have separate limits (both 25 requests). Therefore, clearing out history won't affect your collections. Archived collections don't count towards this limit either, so deleting archived collections (as suggested in the Github thread) won't have any effect either.

Other then moving to a paid plan to avoid archiving collections, you can "Unshare" the collections so that they don't get archived. To do so, you have to remove them from all workspaces, but your personal workspace. If you go to "Share Collection", you'd be able to see all the workspaces the collection is in. If you still want to share the collections with other people, you can export it and give it to them. The downside it that you'll have to do this manually export/import every time you make a change to the collection.